# Why is this keras network not "learning"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to build a convolutional neural network to classify cats and dogs(a very basic problem because I want to learn). One of the approaches that I'm trying is to have 2 output neurons to check the class(instead of using only 1 and make 0 --> cats and 1--> dogs for example) but for some reason the network is not learning, could someone help me?

This is the model:

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop,Adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, Callback, EarlyStopping
from keras.utils import np_utils

optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-4)
objective = 'categorical_crossentropy'


def classifier():
    
    model = Sequential()
    
    model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same',input_shape=train.shape[1:],activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_first"))

    model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same',activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_first"))
    
    model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same',activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_first"))
    
    model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same',activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format="channels_first"))
    

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    
    model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(Dense(2))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    
    print("Compiling model...")
    model.compile(loss=objective, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

print("Creating model:")
model = classifier()
```

this is the main loop

```python
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Dropout, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Activation
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, Callback, EarlyStopping
from keras.utils import np_utils

epochs = 5000
batch_size = 16

class LossHistory(Callback):
    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.losses = []
        self.val_losses = []
        
    def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
        self.losses.append(logs.get('loss'))
        self.val_losses.append(logs.get('val_loss'))

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4, verbose=1, mode='min')        
       

def run():
    
    history = LossHistory()
    print("running model...")
    model.fit(train, labels, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,
              validation_split=0.10, verbose=2, shuffle=True, callbacks=[history, early_stopping])
    
    print("making predictions on test set...")
    predictions = model.predict(test, verbose=0)
    return predictions, history

predictions, history = run()

loss = history.losses
val_loss = history.val_losses
```

and here is one example of the input labels:

```python
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       ..., 
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1]])
```

PS: don't bother about the input format, because using the same input it works for a binary classifier.

Comment: Reduce the drop rate of dropout layer e.g to 0.2. 0.5 is big number because your are droping half of the neurons.

Comment: hey @Mitiku, thanks. After changing the dropout, it started learning. thanks :D

Comment: hey @Mitiku, I forgot the mark it. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rate` argument of dropout layer is too large. Dropout layers are used as regularization technique for deep learning neural networks, and to overcome overfitting. Your `rate` argument specifies how much percentage to drop from previous layer's activation while training. 0.5 `rate` means dropping 50% of the previous layer's activation. Though some times this large percentage of `rate` argument is feasible, some times it hinders the learning rate of neural networks. So you should be careful while choosing the `rate` argument of dropout layer.